# How to prevent a file from being Directly Downloaded & Veiwed Via URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Using Apache with a folder (on my Localhost) like:

```
http://localhost/test/
```

In the folder, the files are:

- `Examle.m3u`
- `Guide.xml.gz`
- `.htaccess`

When I point my browser at website at `http//localhost/test/example.m3u`, the browser attempts to download the file.

I want to prevent the browser showing or attempting to download the file at `http://localhost/test/example.m3u` when typed directly in the address bar.

I Have been looking at using a transparent proxy to somehow setup a tunnel and using a X-Foward Header?

Any Help pointing me in the right direction will be much appreciated and a huge help.

Comment: If you don't want to publish that file directly, then why do you place it inside the file hierarchy you publish via http? It belongs somewhere else where the http server cannot directly access it! Then use a simple router script to access file with more control about who is given what and how.

Comment: if your hosting don't allow to do what **arkascha** recommand, you can deny the access of a directory in putting `Deny from All` in the .htaccess file

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the reply, Would you happen to know any guides that could help me understand how to go about setting a router script up.

Comment: Sorry, no, I doubt there is a specific guide on that. But just give it a try: create a php script that accepts a file name (or path) as an argument, checks if the file actually exists inside an internally configured location unknown to the client, decides if the client is authorized (by whatever means you want to consider), then sends a few headers like file type, disposition, name and size and finally delivers the content of the file. Pretty straight forward. That way you have one central "file delivery" authority where you are in control.

Answer (score 2):

In your .htaccess files you can list the files that you don't want to be downloaded like in this sample above where the blocked files are docs and pdfs

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(doc|pdf)$">
     Order Allow,Deny
     Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: That does stop it from downloading the files but now how do i go about giving apache a route to the files so they can still be accessible to the server sorry if i am not making sense just trying to wrap me head around  how to do this..